# Spring-WS client retry logic

Tags: java, soap-client, spring-ws

I am trying to implement retry mechanism to call a SOAP webservice a few times until it gives me desired output as response . I wrote client using Spring -WS webservicetemplate configuring in xml . please suggest if there is any elegant way to retry these calls.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  There are a number of ways to do retry mechanisms, but generally it's a bit scary for a framework; since if it retries a credit card transaction 3 times and it partially succeeds, you could end up with 3 charges (and there are a number of other scenarios like this).  The crux of it is going to be - check for an error; and if that error indicates a retry would help then try again unless your retry count has been met.  But it's hard to give you the code for that; since you didn't give your request code.... :).

Comment: Moved details out of comment and into the question.

Comment: Thanks. Hoping to get answer soon.

Comment: the question is way too wide..
please refer to this article to get at least a general idea of what you are asking..
http://xpadro.blogspot.it/2013/12/retry-web-service-operations-with.html